# SUMPRODUCT using filter as criteria

Tags: excel, array-formulas, sumproduct

I want to add up the Balances (Column I) for the rows in which the Division (Column B) is "Service".  This formula works:

=SUMPRODUCT(($B7:$B500="SERVICE")*I7:I500)

...which surprised me because I've never really understood SUMPRODUCT before.

Now instead of simply finding the "Service" rows, I want to use my filter to select "Service" or any other value of Column B. So now I need the formula to detect what the filter is set form.

I suspect there's a way to extract what's visible in Column B. Or maybe there's a way to do this using COUNTIF and/or SUBTOTAL.

Comment: Hi there.  Actually, the simplest answer is to say that you should use an alternate aggregation function like "SUBTOTAL" or "AGGREGATE", since these are able to ignore "hidden" rows, as a result of data filtering.  That way, you don't have to worry about what the value is that's chosen in the filter, and trying to perform a calculation based on that - those aggregation functions will take care of it.  (Plus, what would you expect to happen if multiple values were selected in the data filter?)

Comment: However, I did do some playing around (and then more investigation) into how easily the selected filter value could be determined (or, let's say, at least the first filter value that was selected, if there are multiples).  I'll be honest that I've not specifically tried to do this, myself, in the past ..... turns out it's not an easy task to accomplish without adding extra columns, or resorting to VBA.  The majority of Excel's functions (that you might think are candidates, like MIN or MAX) only work on numeric values, not alpha.  Someone else might have an answer, but I don't know

Comment: I believed that Column B would have only one filtered choice, but it turns out I was mistaken. Plus, we may filter on other columns as well,  so the whole question is moot. I'll leave the question posted in case an any eventual answers help someone.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can understand, your current formula is working, however you need the flexibility to select the keyword in column B.
If that is correct, what I would suggest, is to create in a cell let's say "A1" a data validation list with the keyword you desire to have a SUMPRODUCT.
The formula would be modified as follow:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B7:$B500=$A$1)*I7:I500)
```